# issue with session across subdomain only for google chrome

Tags: php, session, subdomain

I've faced a strange issue with session across subdomain only for google chrome.
I have two subdomain a.mydomain.com & b.mydomain.com.
if I open a.mydomain.com first on browser & then open b.mydomain.com & login from there then I'm not getting the session in a.mydomain.com. But if I login first from b.mydomain.co & then open a.mydomain.com I'm getting the session in a.mydomain.com.

I'm unable to solve this. Please help

Comment: Make sure you are setting the session cookie from both domain at `.mydomain.com`. It seems you are not setting the session cookie to `.mydomain.com` when you login from  `a.mydomain.com`

Comment: you are getting me wrong. session in a.mydomain is not working only if I happen to open a.mydomain.com on browser before b.domain.com. This problem I'm not facing in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the session cookies in your browser. What are the domain settings on them? Possibly your sites have different cookie settings. where the `a` site is setting a `.mydomain.com` cookie, and the `b` site is setting `b.mydomain.com`, prevent the cookie from appear on site `a`.

Comment: It seems this property is not respected by all browser, i am getting crazy, i also changed the name of the session according to the host to get it clear.

Answer (score 1):

silly me, found the answer so liked to share it

I used session.cookie_domain only for b.mydomain.com & not for a.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Cookies will only be inherited when setting them on the domain one level above. Setting the cookie on example.com will inherit it to www.example.com, foo.example.com, etc.
Setting a cookie on www.example.com will not show the cookie to foo.example.com.